# WCF Service in Firebase

Tags: firebase, wcf, firebase-hosting

I have hosted my WEB APP in firebase. It consists of a WEB APP that calls a WCF Service also hosted in firebase.
The problem is that at the time of calling service, firebase returns 404 error.
The app and the service work perfectly in my local IIS, so it's not a code error.

I commented to them that the error that it gives me is that it does not find this page (404) when in fact I would be returning the result of my query.

https://recoveryerpwcf.firebaseapp.com/General.svc/Select?tabla=Compania&codigo=0&columnas=%5BCodigoAgrupado%5D%7C%7C%5BDescripcionAgrupada%5D&filtro=&columnasf=%5BDescripcionAgrupada%5D&top=999&_=1528745507843

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Hosting can serve static assets, and (by connecting it to Cloud Functions) Node.js scripts.

There is no way to host a WCF service in Firebase.